# $_POST behavior strange - it works opposite as expected?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, isset

I have the below html form and submit it to the php file (workcard_done.php). My problem is when I submit the code it echos the **else `echo "nothing here";`** If I set the not (!) operator on isset, I get the wanted result? It should work fine with `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit']))`.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the below code it is driving me crazy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<head>
<title>yoyo</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="workcard_done.php" name="workCard_open" method="POST">
<br>
<table>
<tr>
<th>title 1</th>
<th>title 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="price[]" value="" class="matr_price"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="price[]" value="" class="matr_price"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total incl. VAT:</td>
<td><span type="text" name"sum[]" id="sum">0</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name"submit" class="submit" value="Done"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**workcard_done.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>title...</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $user = $_POST['user'];

  print_r($name);
  echo "<br>";  
  print_r($price);
  echo "<br>";
  print_r($user);
  echo "<br>";
}
else {
  echo "nothing here";
}
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

**If setting the not (!) operator on isset, I get the below wanted result.**

```
Array
(
    [0] => slange
    [1] => rfd
)
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 200
)
Array
(
    [user] => 2
)
```

Comment: `! isset($_POST['submit']) && ! empty($_POST['submit'])` always evaluate to `FALSE`. If `$_POST['submit']` is not set then it is empty and `! empty()` evaluates to `FALSE`. If it is set then `! isset()` evaluates to FALSE. Each way the complete expression is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed an `=` on `<input type="submit" name"submit"`

Comment: ... sorry @JimboSlice my bad, you are right. everything works now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this line of HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name"submit" class="submit" value="Done"/>
```

The Submit button has no name, that's why `isset($_POST['submit']) == FALSE`. Add the equal sign (`=`) where it belongs and suddenly your problem will disappear.

Comment: Use `print_r($_POST);` to see what your script receives from the browser.

Comment: ... sorry @axiac my bad, you are right. everything works now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check on $_POST, not on $_POST['submit'].

What if an user presses enter? The submit button will never fire and this value won't exist.

Don't forget the CRSF token by the way.

Comment: checking on `$_POST` is always true, since empty fields will still return a string with a length of 0

Comment: isset($_POST) => yep, always true
!empty($_POST) => nope, only when it's filled.
So this way is preferred above checking the submit button.

Comment: If the user presses `Enter` on a text or password field then the form is submitted and the value of the `submit` button is also sent, if it's not disabled. If the form contains more than one `submit` button, the first one that is not disabled is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `=` as other answers state, but you're also trying to access `$_POST['user']`, while none of your input fields has the name `user`.